# How to set-up forwarding with a google apps gmail account?

Tags: google-apps

I want to make all emails from info@mydomain.com google apps email account forward to multiple users. I am trying to follow the instructions given at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957?hl=en but there is no "Forwarding and POP/IMAP" in my settings. All I have is:

- General
- Labels
- Inbox
- Accounts and Import
- Filters and Blocked Addresses
- POP/IMAP
- Download
- Chat
- Labs
- Offline
- Themes

How do I do that for google apps?

Comment: Did you miss the note that reads "**Note: You can only set up forwarding on your computer, and not on the Gmail app.**" in that link?

Comment: All I need to understand is how to forward emails on the gsuite? Are you saying it is not possible?

Comment: It is not supported and not possible. Why can't you use a computer to setup forwarding?

Comment: I don't understand why you keep talking about a "computer" to set it up. I am using Google G Suite on the cloud, there is nothing unusual about it. Just a company account.

Comment: You may want to follow the [instructions and notes here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957?hl=en). I suggest pay attention to the **Note**. Or if you have direct access to the mail server on `mydomain.com`, simply create a forwarder for the mailbox `info` in there.